# Bug/ Error showing up in the "Add Image" modal dialog pop up?

Tags: bug

[image: https://i.imgur.com/6ezpXJE.png]

Cant add picture so uploading the Screenshot Link as I am able to.

```
Opera 45.0
Version information

Version:    45.0.2552.888 (PGO) - Downloading update 100%
Update stream:  Stable
System: Windows 8.1 64-bit (WoW64)
Browser identification

Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36 OPR/45.0.2552.888
```

Comment: What browser? What OS? Do you have any userscripts or add-on's or extensions that might be modifying the behaviour of the page? Do you have JavaScript enabled? Are you using an adblocking or noscript style add-on? Where exactly do you see this behaviour, what steps do you take?

Comment: The dialogue works well for me. Can you try a different browser or a new clean profile in your current browser with add-on's disabled?

Comment: @Mokubai - It was working fine until yesterday/ 2 days back. Will try with a  fresh reboot and above suggested stuff.

Comment: Might also be worth opening your JS console and look for any errors. And clearing the browser cache for the site is always worth a try as well.

Comment: We've seem similar reports when people had Norton extensions for Chrome setup - unlikely to be the exact same thing here (given you are using Opera), but anything that would block CSS/JS in the browser could cause this. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/296423/strange-dialog-when-adding-an-image-to-a-qa and its duplicates.

Comment: Will look into it. It was working recently and nothing was added or changed on the system. Let's see if we can trace the issue. Thanks for the pointers. Will get back soon.

Comment: @Oded - I dont have Norton but let's see if/how something else is playing into it.